# IBM MQ: AMQ7017 'Log not available'

Tags: ibm-mq

When trying to start a queue manager I get a `AMQ7017 Log not available` message. I have checked, the `LogPath` for the queue manager in the `mqs.ini` file is correct. When the problem started I checked and there were two log files in the log folder for the manager: `S000000` and `S0000002`. I simply copied the first one and renamed the copy to `S000001` (with the correct number of zeroes). Still the same error.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I hope its not a production qmgr. Few options below.

1. You can restore the missing log file from backup and try to start.
2. Create a qmgr of the same name (in another machine) with the same qm.ini. Basically the log setting should be the same as this qmgr. Copy the log files from that machine to this qmgr and try to start the qmgr. If it starts, the qmgr might recover the persistent messages from the queue files.  This is not recommended by IBM, but works in some situations.  If its a non-production qmgr, this is the best way.
3. recreate the qmgr